# What is the best way to create Javascript components?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, dom-events, ajaxform

I am studying how to create components in Javascript. Is it a good idea to create components by extending the HTMLElement? or there is another way.
If you can advise me please which is the most optimal way

I was practising with this example that I found on the web, is it a good way?

```
<my-component id="a">Hello</my-component>
<my-component id="b">Hello</my-component>

<script>
 class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
   get id () {
     console.log ('get id', super.id);
     return super.id;
   }

   set id (value) {
     console.log ('get id', value);
     super.id = value;
   }

   get innerHTML () {
     console.log ('get innerHTML', super.innerHTML);
     return super.innerHTML;
   }

   set innerHTML (value) {
     console.log ('set innerHTML', value);
     super.innerHTML = value;
   }
 }

 customElements.define ('my-component', MyComponent);

 const el1 = document.querySelector ('#a');
 el1.id    = 'c';

 const el2     = document.querySelector ('#b');
 el2.innerHTML = '<h2>Hello</h2>';

</script>
```

Comment: You might check out `Polymer` from Google. (http://www.polymer-project.org). Their `lit-element` may be a more component-friendly starting place than `HTMLElement`. (https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/try)

Comment: What is the difference between use litHtml and htmlElement?

Comment: `HTMLElement` is a built-in part of the DOM in JavaScript for the browser, and `lit-element` is a higher-level interface that only works on webpages that incorporate Polymer, which is a framework intended for working with web components. (You can see `HTMLElement` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement, `lit-element` https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/, and `Polymer` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/polymer/polymer_quick_guide.htm)

Comment: I understand, it is a framework like react js that facilitates the work, but if I wanted I could create components inheriting directly from htmlElement and there would be no problems (just more work, am I correct?). Thanks

Comment: I think you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're looking for.  If you are trying to build a more complex web app, I would recommend using a frontend framework such as React, Angular, or Vue because of how elegant they make it to write complex frontends.

However, if you are more looking to learn about web components and different ways of building frontends I would encourage you to try building simple projects with a bunch of different tools and frameworks you can find to see what you like best and go from there.  One of the frameworks I mentioned could be a good starting place.